# Updating PHP 5.3 to 5.4 in CentOS

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, php

I followed [this](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-apache-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) tutorial to update PHP from 5.3 version to 5.4. My distro is CentOS 5.5.

After running the following command:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install httpd php php-common
```

I get following error:

```
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
php53-common-5.3.3-13.el5_8.i386 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> php53-common conflicts with php-common
Error: php53-common conflicts with php-common
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the following code and I succeeded to install PHP 5.4:

```
yum erase php-common  
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install php
```

Comment: Does phpmyadmin works in your system after php-common replace by php524?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `php-zts` and recompile this extension or regenerate the RPM package for it when you finished installation of php 5.4.

`yum remove php-zts`

Comment: Thanks, now it say: Error: `php53-common conflicts with php-common`

Comment: In general, large unwieldy cluster*.*. packages are updated as a group. Remove all `php-` packages, then `yum install php php-common php-zts php-devel` and whatnot, and keep adding missing packages to the yum command line until it does not complain anymore.

Comment: Is there any way that this be done automatically? Some times ago I uninstalled some packages in Ubuntu and it removed a lot of other packages as well, and  a lot of trouble ....

Answer (score -1):

is easy,use remi repo

```
$ wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm 
$ wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm 
$ rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
```

change enabled to 1

```
vim /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
$ yum clean all 
$ yum makecache
$ yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=remi update php
```